# PHP files in an HTML5 project

Tags: mac, php, netbeans, ide, html5

I created a HTML5 Project using Netbeans 7.3, but sometimes I need to run PHP code when testing locally. *How do I run PHP code when testing my project locally?*

The default Netbeans testing URL is `localhost:8383` but this does not point to PHP-capable web server which is port 80.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200559/netbeans-7-3-new-html5-project-where-to-place-php-and-mvc

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows OS, just add IIS from add/remove programs and install PHP following the instructions on their website. I've successfully done this on Windows 7.

**Update**

For macs, you can *try* [this](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html), I've never used it but it's the first result for 'php server for mac'. Bottom line is you have to install a php server on your machine if you want to run php code locally, but it's nothing to be scared of.

**2nd Update**

If you already have a php server installed and configured, then it's a matter of changing your web server's listening port. So, you have two options (maybe only one because I've read that sometimes changing the default port on macs isn't possible, although I don't know why or how it's not)

1) Change the only listening port, by altering the httpd.conf file and changing the line that reads

```
Listen 80
```

2) Add a listening port, by adding a line that reads

```
Listen 8383
```

After either of these you will have to restart your httpd service on the machine.

Comment: How about for a Mac? (I added that tag now)

Comment: Thank you, but I already have PHP installed. My question is how to run PHP files under an HTML5 project (new to Netbeans 7.3) when testing locally? Because the local testing URL Netbeans provides is port 8383 and my PHP server is on port 80.

Comment: @Hope4You what are you using for PHP?

Comment: Built-in PHP on OS X Lion (Apache server)

Comment: @Hope4You I've given more information.

Comment: I just tried adding listen port 8383, and the PHP is still not executing. Any ideas? Note: The Netbeans help says that it is running the files on a "lightweight embedded web server" when the "Embedded Lightweight" option is selected (which is what I use).

Comment: Looks like this is a known issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200559/netbeans-7-3-new-html5-project-where-to-place-php-and-mvc